# Undefined props in vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I'm on progress to learning `Laravel Jetstream` with stack `inertia.js` and `vuejs 3`. 
For now i want to make a dynamic data pagination and this is my component :

*User Controller*

```
public function filter(Request $request)
{
    return Inertia::render('Users/Index', [
        'filters' => $request->all('search', 'trashed'),
        'users' => User::orderByName()
                    ->filter($request->only('search', 'trashed'))
                    ->paginate()
                    ->transform(function ($user) {
                        return [
                            'id' => $user->id,
                            'username' => $user->username,
                            'name' => $user->name,
                            'profile_photo_url' => $user->profile_photo_url,
                            'email' => $user->email,
                            'created_at' => $user->created_at->diffForHumans(),
                        ];
                    }),
    ]);
}
```

*Parent Component*

```
<pagination class="mt-6" :links="users.links" />
```

*Child Component*

```
<template>
    <div v-if="links.length > 3">
        <div class="flex flex-wrap -mb-1">
            <template v-for="(link, key) in links">
                <div
                    v-if="link.url === null"
                    :key="key"
                    class="mr-1 mb-1 px-4 py-3 text-sm leading-4 text-gray-400 border rounded"
                    v-html="link.label"
                />
                <inertia-link
                    v-else
                    :key="key"
                    class="mr-1 mb-1 px-4 py-3 text-sm leading-4 border rounded hover:bg-white focus:border-indigo-500 focus:text-indigo-500"
                    :class="{ 'bg-white': link.active }"
                    :href="link.url"
                    v-html="link.label"
                />
            </template>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        links: Array,
    },
};
</script>
```

and unfortunatelly i got an error `$props.links is undefined` and i don't know why i got this error. 
Could anybody here to help me for fixing this problem ?
Thanks

Comment: The provided code seems correct, so we need more code. Where is your `users.links` defiend? Make sure it is defined, before you try to use it. Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: @tauzN i got undefined when i see data users in console.